# Can you set a custom x-forwarded-host header in a CSRF form page?

Tags: web-application, javascript, csrf

Can you set a custom `x-forwarded-host` header in a CSRF form page (not xhr)?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot explicitly set any HTTP headers in a HTML form apart from choosing the `Content-Type` between two predefined values. This means you also cannot set some `x-forwarded-host` header.